# How to modify collection's elements with a spliterator

Tags: java-8, spliterator

After much searching, I just found that the only operation that is supported by `Spliterator` is to READ elements from a `Collection`.

Can someone tell me about another operation in CRUD that can be supported by `Spliterator`. I tried to modify elements in a `Collection` using a `Spliterator` but it didn't work:

```
    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set.add(2);
    set.add(3);
    set.add(5);
    set.add(6);
    Spliterator<Integer> si = set.spliterator();
    Spliterator<Integer> sa  = si.trySplit();
    while(sa.tryAdvance(e ->  e= ++e));

    System.out.println("original iterator");
    while(si.tryAdvance(e-> e = ++e));
    System.out.println(set.toString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) cannot modify an underlying [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), mainly because `Spliterator` (unlike [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)) is not a strictly `Collection`-bound interface.

The definition of `Iterator` (from [`Iterator`'s JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)):

> An iterator over a collection. [...]
>
> Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.

The definition of `Spliterator` (from [`Spliterator`'s JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html)):

> An object for traversing and partitioning elements of a source. The source of elements covered by a `Spliterator` could be, for example, an array, a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), an IO channel, or a generator function.

---

*EDIT*: I just read the code you posted. In this code, you try to mutate an immutable `Integer` instance inside a `Spliterator` call. In this case, neither `Iterator` nor `Spliterator` can work, because the elements are immutable.

Use a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) (or an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)) for this, together with a [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) followed by [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-).

Comment: I do not agree with the concept of Iterator is strictly bound to Collection objects as the following code statement is also valid and fetch an equivalent iterator from infinite source stream. So the the concept of removal with well defined semantics does not hold true. `final Iterator<Integer> numbers = Stream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1).iterator();`

Comment: Well, I may have exaggerated by using words "strictly" and `Collection`. Not "strictly" because - as you've shown - we encounter `Iterator`s in many other places (e.g. before Java 8, people - me included - often wrote custom `Iterator` implementations). On the other hand, `Iterator` is **defined** to iterate over a `Collection` (that's why it has a [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method - it is optional, though). `Spliterator`, on the other hand, explicitly states it's **not** necessarily `Collection`-bound.

Comment: The explanation is misleading, as even calling `forEach` directly on the collection would not change the fact that a consumer like `e ->  e= ++e` bears even two obsolete operations without an effect. `++e` modifies the parameter `e` and the assignment `e=` modifies the parameter again, to assign it the same value it already has due to the `++e` operation. For that, it doesn’t matter whether we use `int` or `Integer`, the parameter *variable* is mutable, but like with methods, modifying a parameter has no effect on the caller, regardless of which interface we’re using.

Comment: @Holger: I edited my answer as soon as I read the code and noticed what it does. I'm not sure if I should have done anything more than appending to the current answer. Would prepending to the answer be considered OK?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here as mentioned by the accepted answer is `Integer` objects are immutable, so neither consuming your set through its iterator or spliterators will work, because you can not modify an integer instance *in-place*. However, if your objects are considered mutable,  you can fetch them through `Iterator#next` or in the consumer of `Spliterator#tryAdvance` and modify them as regular mutable objects (e.g: through exposed setters).

As a work around solution, you can stream over your set, mapping each integer instance to a new integer instance with the desired changes, from there you can collect them back into a new `TreeSet<Integer>`.

```
final Set<Integer> newSet = set.stream()
    .map(number -> number + 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```